# Text Folding in Android

Tags: android, textedit

i just want to ask, is it possible to expand or collapse section of text on TextEdit in Android ?

Answer (score 3):

Inside your Activity (or Fragment):

```
    boolean expanded = false;
    textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text1);

    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (expanded) {
                textView.setMaxLines(3);
            } else {
                textView.setMaxLines(100);
            }
            expanded = !expanded;
        }
    });
```

Inside xml file:

```
                   <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="none"
                    android:maxLines="3"
                    android:padding="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/info_about_smth"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
```

In this way, whenever you click on the text, it will automatically folded by decreasing the max lines.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean either [EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) or it's parent class, [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html). Unfortunately, these do not support collapsible sections. You'd have to simulate that by changing the text programmatically. The only thing that comes close, I think, is [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html), but I suspect that is not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide any View by setting it's visibility to gone :

```
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

- View.GONE => This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.
- View.INVISIBLE => This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.
- View.VISIBLE => This view is visible.

With this you might be able to expand and collapse your EditText .